# Parsing aws ec2 describe-instances to get all private ip addresses

Tags: json, amazon-ec2, command-line, jq, aws-cli

Two of my EC2 instances have 3 IPs each. I managed to successfully grab a list of JSON objects:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances | jq '.Reservations[] | .Instances[] | (.Tags | { "iname": ( map ( select(.Value | contains("my-vm")))[] | .Value ) } ) + ( { "ip": ( .NetworkInterfaces[].PrivateIpAddress) } )' | jq -s .
```

Giving me the following result:

```
[
  {
    "iname": "my-vm-b",
    "ip": "10.11.2.145"
  },
  {
    "iname": "my-vm-b",
    "ip": "10.11.1.146"
  },
  {
    "iname": "my-vm-b",
    "ip": "10.11.10.144"
  },
  {
    "iname": "my-vm-a",
    "ip": "10.11.1.9"
  },
  {
    "iname": "my-vm-a",
    "ip": "10.11.10.125"
  },
  {
    "iname": "my-vm-a",
    "ip": "10.11.2.85"
  }
]
```

and then I added to the command the following:

```
... | jq ' group_by(.iname)[] | {(.[0].iname): [.[] | .ip]}' | jq -s .
```

To finally get the list of objects the way I wanted:

```
[
  {
    "my-vm-a": [
      "10.11.1.9",
      "10.11.10.125",
      "10.11.2.85"
    ]
  },
  {
    "my-vm-b": [
      "10.11.2.145",
      "10.11.1.146",
      "10.11.10.144"
    ]
  }
]
```

Notice I had to call jq like 4 times. I know I must be doing something wrong so I was wondering if I could do it with a single jq call.

Thanks!

Comment: it would be better it you could post a testable initial `aws ec2 describe-instances` output so we could construct an optimized approach

Comment: Side-note: The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) has a `--query` parameter that could take out some of your JQ calls, but the final steps would still need some manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily eliminate the calls to `jq -s` by wrapping expressions as appropriately in square brackets, or maybe better, using `map`.

For example, your last pair of jq calls can be simplified to:

```
jq 'group_by(.iname) | map({(.[0].iname): [.[] | .ip]})'
```

The following should allow you to reduce the four calls to one:

```
[.Reservations[]
 | .Instances[]
 | (.Tags | { "iname": ( map ( select(.Value | contains("my-vm")))[] | .Value ) } )
    + ( { "ip": ( .NetworkInterfaces[].PrivateIpAddress) } ) ]
| group_by(.iname) | map({(.[0].iname): [.[] | .ip]})
```

However, I would advise against using `contains` here, unless you fully understand the complications.

Answer (score 0):

Before you go into trying to simplify your jq calls, I think it would be more beneficial to first look at the source data and how it relates to the result you want.

Ignoring a lot of the other details in the data, I think we can agree that your data looks sorta like this:

```
{
    "Reservations": [
        {
            "Instances": [
                {
                    "NetworkInterfaces": [
                        { "PrivateIpAddress": "10.11.2.145" },
                        { "PrivateIpAddress": "10.11.1.146" },
                        { "PrivateIpAddress": "10.11.10.144" }
                    ],
                    "Tags": [
                        { "Key": "Name", "Value": "my-vm-b" }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "NetworkInterfaces": [
                        { "PrivateIpAddress": "10.11.1.9" },
                        { "PrivateIpAddress": "10.11.10.125" },
                        { "PrivateIpAddress": "10.11.2.85" }
                    ],
                    "Tags": [
                        { "Key": "Name", "Value": "my-vm-a" }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

With something that looks like this, your jq query can simply be:

```
[.Reservations[].Instances[] |
    {
        (.Tags|from_entries.Name): [.NetworkInterfaces[].PrivateIpAddress]
    }
]
```

No intermediate results needed. Just a few things of note here.

- The tags are already an array of key/value pairs, you can easily read values from here converting them to an object first using `from_entries`
- You are selecting instances based on an existence of a tag value containing `"my-vm"`. I'm not sure you even need to do this, I don't know what your data looks like but they are likely in a fixed name so you should just use that name.